how to merge 2 xml's in python
XML 1:
<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>

XML 2:
<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>

Required output:
 <invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>
<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>

This is the output i am getting from the following program:
 <invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>
</invoicecopy>

My program :
xml_files = glob.glob(XML_DIR +"/*.xml")
print ("xml files are " , xml_files)
xml_element_tree = None
for filename in xml_files:
    data = ElementTree.parse(filename).getroot()
    print (data)
    for result in data.iter('invoiceCopy'):
     if xml_element_tree is None:
       newfilename = "print" + datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')+ ".xml"
       print(newfilename)
       xml_element_tree=data
     else:
       for statement in data.iter('invoiceCopy'):
        xml_element_tree.append(statement)

    if xml_element_tree is not None:
    result1 = ''
    m_encoding = "iso-8859-1"
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(xml_element_tree))
    xml_string = dom.toprettyxml()
    for result in xml_string.split('\n'):
       if not result.strip() == '':
         result1=result1+result+"\n"
    part1, part2 = result1.split('?>')        
    with open("/data/ebpp/star/fh/invoicecopy/print/" + newfilename, "w") as xfile:
       xfile.write(part1 + 'encoding=\"{}\"?>'.format(m_encoding) + part2)
       xfile.close()

Why is the 2nd xml appended inside the root of first xml? Please help

Please correct your xml! Required xml isn’t valid xml!

Note: Your required example is not valid xml! You need always one root element.
You have a tipo in invoicecopy and invoiceCopy.
I assume you will get such a xml?
You have to append the document element only. Append function is described in the python xml documentation:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

first = """<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoiceCopy>"""

second = """<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoiceCopy>"""

root_first = ET.fromstring(first)
document2 = ET.fromstring(second)[0] 

root_first.append(document2)

ET.dump(root_first)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root_first)
ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
tree.write('output.xml')

Output:
<invoiceCopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoiceCopy>

Alternative create a new root, e.g invoices:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

first = """<invoicecopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>"""

second = """<invoicecopy>
<document>
    <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
    <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
    <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
    <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
</document>
</invoicecopy>"""

root = ET.Element('invoices')
invoice1 = ET.fromstring(first)
invoice2 = ET.fromstring(second)

root.append(invoice1)
root.append(invoice2)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
ET.dump(tree)

tree.write('output.xml')

Output:
<invoices>
  <invoicecopy>
    <document>
      <invoicenumber>1245678</invoicenumber>
      <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
      <pdffilename>12345678.pdf</pdffilename>
      <sendingsystemid>ABC</sendingsystemid>
    </document>
  </invoicecopy>
  <invoicecopy>
    <document>
      <invoicenumber>2222222</invoicenumber>
      <invoicedate>2024-06-06</invoicedate>
      <pdffilename>2222222.pdf</pdffilename>
      <sendingsystemid>XYZ</sendingsystemid>
    </document>
  </invoicecopy>
</invoices>

The principle is always the same, if you will merge several files in a subfolder, you can define a function:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

def add_invoice(root, invoice):
    root.append(invoice)
    return root

def write_invoices(root):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
    ET.dump(tree)
    tree.write('output.xml')
    
root = ET.Element('invoices')

files = os.listdir(path='./xml_folder/.')
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".xml"):
        invoice = ET.parse(f"./xml_folder/{f}").getroot()
        root = add_invoice(root, invoice)

write_invoices(root)


what is i have more than 2 XMLs? The above question was just an example with 2 XMLs. But in actual case it will be more than 2.


Why is the 2nd xml appended inside the root of first xml?

Because your code is doing just that:
     if xml_element_tree is None:
       newfilename = "print" + datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')+ ".xml"
       print(newfilename)
       xml_element_tree=data
     else:
       for statement in data.iter('invoiceCopy'):
        xml_element_tree.append(statement)

On the first iteration, xml_element_tree is None so it just uses data directly.
On the subsequent iterations, it … appends all of the invoiceCopy elements to xml_element_tree (itself an invoiceCopy element).

XML trees can only have one root so you’re gonna have to create your own new root element before the loop, or use a Python list.
